# Approaching a dictionary using parameters in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, config

I'm writing a generic Python script that knows how to deal with 4 different SQL tables - according to the argument that is sent (the table name).
Each table name has different constants - such as files paths, files names, query etc.
I've tried writing a config.py file that will contain a dictionary for each table, and then I could get the right constant by approaching the right dictionary.

Example:

```
Table1 = dict(
    DBName='db1',
    FolderPath='C:\\MySQL\\Table1',
    LogPath='C:\\MySQL\\Table1\\LogFile.txt' 
)
Table2 = dict(
    DBName='db2',
    FolderPath='C:\\MySQL\\Table2',
    LogPath='C:\\MySQL\\Table2\\LogFile.txt' 
)
```

The way I wanted to get to the dictionary is:

```
import config

name = sys.argv[1]
DBname = config.name['DBName']
```

the only problem is - I can't write "name" variable there, I have to write the exact dictionary name...

so - is there any way I can get a dictionary using a variable?
if not - is there a better way to create what I need (get constants according to an argument sent to the script)?
Thank you very much!

Comment: what about writing a dict of a dict? Like `config = dict( Table1 = dict( [...] ))`? Then, the string you get from the user is usable to retrieve the configuration dict.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
config = {
         "name":{
                  'DBName':'blah'
                }
         }
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed, and so simple... Thank you!!